# Запуск программы в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: появляется при запуске run]

Появляется при запуске run. Как это убрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы запустить программу в IDEA, нужно создать конфигурацию запуска (что вам и предлагает сделать IDEA). Выберите пункт Edit Configurations в появившемся меню (или в меню Run). В появившемся окне нажмите плюс в левом верхнем углу и выберите Application. Выберите Main class (класс вашей программы, содержащий метод `main`, который нужно выполнить при запуске программы) и дайте конфигурации осмысленное имя. Сохраните конфигурацию и выберите её в меню, располагающемся левее кнопки Run на панели инструментов. После этого вы сможете запускать ваше приложение.

Comment: А  почему пишет is not acceptable

Comment: Где пишет? При каких обстоятельствах?

Comment: В общем я делала все так ,как вы сказали и дошла до Main class 
дальше вот 
https://pp.vk.me/c629121/v629121956/103d6/C2eUu2vrMZU.jpg

Comment: https://pp.vk.me/c629121/v629121956/103e0/EYRYpCheKfg.jpg 
На всякий случай программа выглядит так

Comment: Судя по тому, что IDEA подсвечивает стандартные классы Java красным, что-то не так с настройками JDK. У вас подключён JDK к проекту? File -> Project Structure -> SDKs. Если там ничего нет, нажмите плюс и укажите путь к JDK. После этого снова попробуйте создать конфигурацию запуска и запустить проект.