# Компилятор не может найти главный класс main

Tags: java

Работаю с IntelliJ IDEA. Создал 3 класса, каждый в отдельном файле.

1. Пытаюсь выполнить, компилятор сразу ругается, что не может найти главный класс main
2. После рандомных нажатий, я все-же запустил (как я не знаю), но программа шарашит без остановки, как буд-то цикл не завершается

Первый:

```
public class GameLauncher
{   
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {  
        GuessGame game = new GuessGame();   
        game.startGame();    
    }
}
```

Второй

```
public class GuessGame
{
    Player p1;
    Player p2;
    Player p3;

    public void startGame() {
        p1 = new Player();
        p2 = new Player();
        p3 = new Player();

        int guessp1 = 0;
        int guessp2 = 0;
        int guessp3 = 0;
        boolean p1isRight = false;
        boolean p2isRight = false;
        boolean p3isRight = false;

        int targetNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.println ("Я загадываю число от 0 до 9...");

        while(true) {
            System.out.println ("Число, которое нужно угадать, - " + targetNumber);

            p1.guess();
            p2.guess();
            p3.guess();

            guessp1 = p1.number;
            System.out.println ("первый игрок думает, что это " + guessp1);

            guessp2 = p2.number;
            System.out.println ("второй игрок думает, что это " + guessp2);

            guessp3 = p3.number;
            System.out.println ("третий игрок думает, что это " + guessp3);

            if (guessp1 == targetNumber) {
                p1isRight = true;
            }

            if (guessp2 == targetNumber ) {
                p2isRight = true;
            }

            if (guessp3 == targetNumber ) {
                p3isRight = true;
            }
                if (p1isRight || p2isRight || p3isRight) {
                    System.out.println ("У нас есть победитель!");
                    System.out.println ("первый игрок угадал?" + p1isRight);
                    System.out.println ("второй игрок угадал?" + p2isRight);
                    System.out.println ("третий игрок угадал?" + p3isRight);
                    System.out.println ("Конец игры.");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println ("Игроки должны попробовать ещё раз.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Третий

```
public class Player
{ 
    int number = 0;    
    public void guess()
    {  
        number = (int) (Math.random() * 10); 
        System.out.println ("Думаю, это число " + number);  
    }
}
```

Прошу, если кто может помочь, то попроще объясните, как избежать этих ошибок?

Comment: Запуск программы зависит от используемой IDE. В ее настройках указывается, где находится стартовый метод `main()`. У вас стоит `while (true)` - конечно она "шарашит" в бесконечном цикле, чего вы ожидали? у вас в коде не предусмотренно никаких средств выйти из этой ловушки.

Comment: Хорошо, понял. Благодарю.

Comment: А на первый вопрос? Более подробно можно? буду очень признателен

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/443629/177345

Comment: Благодарю, понял!

Comment: На счет выхода из цикла, вам поможет флаг в виде переменной `boolean` типа (которым сможете останавливать или продолжать цикл), либо `break` для полного выхода из цикла.